# How can I type the “<” symbol via remote desktop with a Nordic keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

I have a Nordic/Norwegian keyboard.  I'm sitting on an iMac with Mountain Lion and are remoting to a Windows 7 computer with Remote Desktop Connection.  I can't find the < or > shortcut (pressing < gives a different character (pipe)).  Does anyone know?

I am aware of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32662/how-can-i-type-the-symbol-via-remote-desktop-with-a-swedish-keyboard) and know how to find most other characters, having tried numerous combinations, but not the < sign.  I also know I can get the character palette, but that is just too slow when I need it relatively often.

**Edit:**  I do not have a numerical pad on the keyboard.  This is the smallest version of the Nordic Mac keyboard and is the default delivered with an iMac in Norway.

**Edit 2:**  Here is a picture of my keyboard:
[image]

**Edit 3:**  Thanks to @koivo I learned that < is called an angle bracket.  I did some googling and found only one unanswered question asked at a different forum ([ars technica](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1131281&hilit=angle%20brackets%20mac)).  I have also tried all sorts of key combinations, but no luck so far.

**Edit 4:**  I have now learned that using [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net) (which is slightly buggy and discontinued in development) or [Royal TS](http://www.royalts.com/main/home.aspx) (which cost money) will give me angle brackets (<) on the angle bracket key itself.  However, I have added a bounty to see if it is possible to do with `Remote Desktop Connection` that comes with the iMac out of the box.

**Edit 5:**  This is written after the correct answer and bounty has been awarded.  Even though a shortcut is available, using the free version of `Royal TSX` is just a simpler solution, as stated in one of the answers!

Comment: Could you try shift-","?

Comment: shift + "," gives me ";" which is what my keyboard says as well.

Comment: you can always use Windows On-Screen Keyboard, just run osk.exe

Comment: @GuidoPreite +1  At least that saves time compared to using the character palette, but still I wish there was a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: → Halvard: on your physical keyboard, is there a key between the left shift and the Z?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Yes.  It is the < key.  But when I remote in to Windows pressing the < key yields the | (pipe) symbol instead.

Comment: I added a picture of my keyboard, so that you know how it looks.  Pardon my photography skills.

Comment: → Halvard: excellent idea. Next candidates of this double failing translation: @ and \`.

Comment: I have now tried those keys in combination with alt, ctrl+alt, fn, shift and fn + shift, but no luck.  It is starting to dawn on me that it might not be available as a shortcut at all.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: → Halvard: could you look at: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11793/how-can-i-set-up-microsoft-remote-desktop-connection-for-mac-to-work-with-the-po
answer from Wheat Williams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to System Preferences:Language & Text:Input Sources. Enable and display the keyboard viewer to get a better view of the next steps.

The first step to try is to turn on the U.S. keyboard.  This should cause shift+comma and shift+period to yield the desired characters, < and >, in place of ; and :.  You can switch between keyboard layouts either using the flag menu that will appear on the right of your menu bar, or by setting keyboard shortcuts.

If switching to the U.S. keyboard layout doesn't work, enable Unicode Hex Input to allow the entry of any Unicode characters by holding down option and typing the hex code point. `<alt/option>003c` yields < (**LESS-THAN SIGN**) and `<alt/option>003e` yields > (**GREATER-THAN SIGN**).  See http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf for a table of common ASCII based Unicode characters. **LESS-THAN SIGN** and **GREATER-THAN SIGN** are the official Unicode names for the angle brackets.

For what it's worth, when I turn on, for example, a Swedish keyboard on my U.S. system, the key to the left of the number 1 offers < and >, as opposed to what I see in your picture.  Showing the keyboard viewer should help clarify what to expect.

From the other question you reference there is also the suggestion by @Tom Gewecke:

> Perhaps you could set up another keystroke to produce @ via system
>   preferences/language & text/text/symbol and text substitution.

Comment: Switching to a U.S. keyboard (or an English keyboard) gives me < from `shift + comma` and > from `shift + period` as stated in this answer.  Some minimal research gave me `alt + shift` as the shortcut to switch between language systems (from EN to NO and back).  How could this simple solution have evaded me? :)  Bounty well deserved.

Comment: For additional info:  I was not able to get Unicode Hex to work, but this might be because of me.

Comment: For additional info II: When I replaced one key with < it worked on my iMac, but when I remoted in to the Windows computer the key was not replaced any longer.  Perhaps if I replaced the key on the Windows machine it might have worked, but then I would have had to unreplace it when not remoting in.

Comment: Glad this worked out for you! Were you able to get Unicode to work locally?

Comment: Yes, I got Unicode Hex input to work on my iMac.  When I remoted in to Windows 7 it did not work though, and I was not able to enable Unicode Hex input on the Windows 7 machine.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection is not supported on anything newer than Snow Leopard 10.6 and if you use it long enough on newer versions of OS X you'll probably run into other issues besides this one such as random crashes from my own personal experience.

Royal TSX is indeed free (with limitations) and has a plugin using FreeRDP under the hood which supports newer versions of RDP configured to require NLA (Windows 7+, Server 2008R2+). My suggestion is that you re-evaluate your decision to stick with RDC, it's a dead end unless Microsoft decides to update it and it's not looking as if they will.

Quote from the Royal TSX site:

> Royal TSX can be downloaded, installed and used for free without any
>   time limit (no trial expiration!) and without a license key. In this
>   mode, the following restrictions are applied:
>
> You cannot have more than 10 connections per Royal TSX application
>   instance. You cannot have more than 10 credentials per Royal TSX
>   application instance. You can open only one Royal TSX document per
>   application instance. AppleScript access is disabled. Also note that
>   all the features of Royal TSX can be used without a license key. No
>   other restrictions apply. To remove the above restrictions, it's
>   required to obtain and enter a license key in Royal TSX.

Comment: +1 for very useful information about `Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection` and `Royal TSX`.  I can confirm that Royal TSX works brilliantly and also gives me the < and > keys.  (I can't give you the bounty though, as you don't answer the question the bounty was for)

Answer (score 0):

As it is Windows you are accessing, try the Alt Codes (alt + numpad) <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> for < and <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> for >

Does that work for you?

Full list: http://www.alt-codes.net/

Comment: Unfortunately I just have a small Apple keyboard without the numeric pad, so I can't test out your suggestion.  I tried it using the regular numbers (alt + (6 + 0)), but that did not work.

Comment: I have also tried `alt + 0060` and `alt + 0062` as I read somewhere, but that did not work either, unfortunately.

Comment: @Halvard - Is it possible to change the keyboard layout within Windows? Or are other users bound to the current layout?

Comment: I am the only user of the Windows computer I am remoting to, so I don't have to take any such considerations.  I have an iMac at home, but an Hewlett Packard (hp) with Windows 7 at work to remote to.  By the way, the key for < at work is to the left of Z, just as for the iMac.  If I remote from my small Windows laptop the < key works fine.

Comment: @Halvard - Two more suggestions: `ctrl + alt + <` and `alt + 7` - and I also found someone who had to use `caps lock` combinations for different brackets, like `caps lock + ctrl + alt + some different numbers` ...

Comment: BTW - I also found out, that the brackets we are looking for are called `angle brackets` or `arrow brackts` ... That helped me for further deepgoogeling...

Comment: Thanks for the name, but it only led to more resultless googling :)  Unfortunately neither the `caps lock`-combinations nor the other suggestions gave angle brackets.  I suspect I have to do something fancy like changing the keyboard layout inside Windows to get this to work, like you suggested.  Or try a different remote desktop program.